# XC8 pconfig.h not selecting chip

Tags: c, pic, mplab, xc8

I am working with XC8 1.20 and a PIC18F66K80 and having some trouble with using the pwm.h library. Whenever I open pwm.h, the only functions that are actually being generated (IE, the #ifdef compile time conditionals are returning true) are for PWM1. After tracing through the code, I came to the pconfig.h file and went down to the section regarding the 18F66K80, and it was all being ignored.

The conditional that was returning false is:

```
#ifdef  __18F66K80
```

In fact, there were no sections that were being compiled. It was like I  had no chip selected, even though the project was targeting the 18F66K80. I went into the compiler macro options and add __18F66K80 as a defined macro, and this block suddenly was compiling, giving me access to PWM2-5.

My question is - what is the correct way to tell pconfig.h what chip I am using? My project settings clearly show the PIC18F66K80 as the target device, but pconfig.h was acting like I had no chosen device. By adding this macro, it appears to work, but I have a feeling this is a hack and not the right way to do things.

Comment: In the source code where you are `#include <pwm.h>`, are you also adding `#include <p18F66K80.h>`? Is the chip include above the pwm include?

Comment: I was including <pic18.h>, which automatically includes the approriate header file for the chip; it is above the pwm.h include. What I noticed while looking just now is that the pic18.h file defines _18F66K80 (via pic18_chip_select.h), but pconfig.h looks for __18F66K80. Note the double underscore on the latter. This might be a bug on microchip's part with inconsistent naming conventions. Manually defining __18F66K80 in the compiler macros seems to be the only fix.

Comment: I've noticed that microchip always has a few bugs in a header for a new chip (if you look, there's thousands of #defines, so it makes sense). Just make sure to upgrade your complier and it tends to go away.